# Failed to create the shared folder

Tags: virtualbox

I'm getting this error message in VirtualBox when trying to create a shared folder:

> Failed to create the shared folder D_DRIVE (pointing to d:\) for the
>   virtual machine test-vm.
>
> Shared folder path 'd:\' is not absolute.
>
> Result Code: E_INVALIDARG (0x80070057) Component: Console Interface:
>   IConsole {8ab7c520-2442-4b66-8d74-4ff1e195d2b6}

Not absolute? How do I share this path?

Comment: Have you tried *D:\*? Capital D, that's it.

Answer (score 0):

If you host is Linux, then you cannot use a Windows path.

If your host is Windows, try with D:\ - it shouldn't make a difference tho.

If you try to import a machine/appliance, then there is [a known issue](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/7941) in older versions of VirtualBox - make sure yours is up to date.